# ¿Porque tengo un error 404 en el document de un componente en el network?

Tags: angular, angular9, angular10, build

Tengo una aplicación desplegada con Lazyload en producción y he notado que tengo este error 404 siempre presente cuando recargo en el navegador.

**Ver Classification**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo pasa cuando refresco la pagina estando parado en una url cualquiera de mi aplicación, pero si navego con el routing de angular no sucede

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿A que se debe ese error de que resalta en rojo la petición classification?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hice unos ajustes al post, espero que se entienda el problema.